# Swiper too high in website

Tags: css, swiper.js

Please help me, i use swiper for my website but swiper too height. If i set max-height , it can't work exactly when responsive - Link for test swiper. phuccode. com

Before i set max-height
[Picture no max height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvELT.png)

After i set max-height
[Picture set-maxheight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Vou.png)

My code

```
<div class="container slider">
    <div class="swiper-container-2">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <a class="img" href="/partner" title="">
                    <img alt ="" src="images/content-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive" title = "">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <a class="img" href="/partner" title="">
                    <img alt ="" src="images/content-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive" title = "">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>                    
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

This CSS: before

```
.slider .swiper-slide {
margin-right: 16px !important;
width: 15%;
 }
 [class*="swiper-container-"] {
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
 }
 .slider a.img img {
      position: absolute;
max-width: 100% !important;
min-width: 10px !important;
min-height: 10px !important;
max-height: auto% !important;
margin: auto;
display: block;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.slider{
    width:970px;
    position:relative;
}
```

This CSS: before

```
.slider .swiper-slide {
margin-right: 16px !important;
width: 15%;
max-height: 180px;
 }
 [class*="swiper-container-"] {
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 1;
      max-height: 200px;
 }
 .slider a.img img {
      position: absolute;
max-width: 100% !important;
min-width: 10px !important;
min-height: 10px !important;
max-height: auto% !important;
margin: auto;
display: block;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.slider{
    width:970px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Share the link or your issue please.

Comment: Hi this is link for my example: http://swiper.phuccode.com/

Comment: so you want big height?

Comment: No i want it small - but if i set max-height, it can't work when resposive